# generating function and binomial distribution - counting

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am trying to understand generating function. I have the following problem:

There are 50 students in the International Mathematical Olympiad (IMO) training programme. 6 of them are to be selected to represent Hong Kong in the IMO. How many ways are there to select 6 students?

The answer:

Generating function is $G(x)=(1+x)^{50}$

But this could just as easily be done with the binomial distribution no?

$$ \binom {50} 6 = 15890700$$

However, unless i am not understanding something correctly, if we plug in $G(6)=(1+6)^{50} $that is $1.79\times10^{42}$ but why am i getting 15890700

Comment: That's not how you use the generating function. The coefficient of $x^6$ of the generating function IS $50\choose 6$.

Comment: I am confused, could yo write it out for me? How do we calculate how many ways to count 6 people using the generating function?

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions are useful for asymptotic estimates. For actual small numbers, they are often more work than directly coming up with the count.

The answer is $\binom{50}{6}$, which you got directly, and is also what the generating-function approach gives, via the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). The binomial theorem states that 
$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{r \ge 0} \binom{n}{r} x^r $$

This means that the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^n$ is $\binom{n}{r}$. In this particular case, with $n = 50$ and $r = 6$, you get $\binom{50}{6}$. Note that

$$(1+x)^{50} = \binom{50}{0} + \binom{50}{1}x + \binom{50}2x^2 + \dots + \binom{50}{6}x^6 + \dots + \binom{50}{50}x^{50}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the generating function, the coefficient of $x^6$ will give the answer you want.

As you say, it is ${50 \choose 6}$.

One way to find  the coefficient of $x^6$  is to take the sixth derivative of $G(x)/6!$ evaluated at $x=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by expanding the generating function of the coefficient of x^6 to find (50 choose 6)

Comment: If you expand $(1+x)^{50}$ you get $1 + 50 x + 1225 x^2 + 19600 x^3 + 230300 x^4 + 2118760 x^5 + 15890700 x^6 + 99884400 x^7 + \cdots + x^{50}$ and the coefficient of $x^6$ gives the answer $15890700$

Comment: The sixth derivative of $G(x)$ is $6! \times 50 \times 49 \times 48 \times 47 \times 46 \times 45 (1+x)^{44}$.  Let $x=0$ and multiply by $6!$

Comment: I'm not sure i understand how you expanded using the derivative to achieve: 1 + 50x + 1225x^2+19600x^3+... etc

Comment: No - I expanded directly.  The sixth derivative at $x=0$ helps find the coefficient of $x^6$.